# Infinite Scroll and Image Hover plugin don't really like each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

After incredibly much effort I finally made **infinite scroll** [(via the plugin)](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/installation/) work with my theme.
Now I got this little riddle for you sherlocks and watsons, which I hope you can solve:

Infinite scroll works, but *on the pages infinite scroll adds* when scrolling down, my [**image hover plugin**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-image-hover-lite/) *doesn't appear anymore*. (and image hover is quite important to my site!!)

When using your browser's dev tools, you will see, that at least the class `wp.imagehoverlite` is applied to the freshly loaded images, which is probably a good sign.

Still- *no social hover buttons...* 
**[Link to my Website](http://www.sparschweinkiller.de)**

In **infinite scroll plugin's settings** then I discovered this box called `callback`:

**Screenshot**[image]

That's a hot lead !

I did my research and found **[this page](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/lightbox-compatibility-code/)** which explains it's function.

> "Since Infinite Scroll dynamically adds new content to the page,
>   sometimes you have to execute additional code to reinitialize those
>   plugins."

This is how I add the hovering effect inside the wordpress loop:

```
                 <div class="gridly-image">

            <img class="wpimagehover alignnone wp-image-<?php echo get_post_thumbnail_id() ?>" src="<?php echo $image_attributes[0]; ?>" alt="" width="300" height="250" data-fburl="<?php the_permalink() ?>" data-tweeturl="<?php the_permalink() ?>" data-pinurl="<?php the_permalink() ?>" data-stumbleuponurl="<?php the_permalink() ?>" data-sstyle="circle" data-sharetxt="<?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>" data-animation="fade" /> 

            </div>
```

**Now we just need to find out, what the heck I need to enter in this big box.
OR - find a way to get social buttons on image hover *without* the plugin.**

I really really really appreciate your help. :)

Comment: P.S. Sorry for the formatting- I don't have enough reputation to do screenshots or more than 2 links.